# Uninstall package using npx

Tags: npm

I trying uninstall package, who I installed by:

```
npx terminalgpt
```

I trying:

```
npm uninstall -g terminalgpt
```

But is not working, how I can uninstall this package?

Comment: Are you running  run npm uninstall -g terminalgpt where package.json is located right?

Comment: if you are not in the same path, it will not work

Comment: I don't know in where path I installed this package, how I can find it?

Comment: in your IDE you should see the package.json, try opening a terminal and go to your project folder, when you are in your project folder use "dir"(windows), or ls(linux), to see what is in the folder, if you see that you are in the path were you can locate the package.json, then you can use the comand, if not, you have to keep looking until you are in the exact path. If you didn't understant i will try to explain in a better way

Comment: I dont remember in which folder I installed it, how I can find it? This is it package: https://github.com/jucasoliveira/terminalGPT, npx terminalgpt chat run in each folder, but I didn't see it globaly.

Comment: My quick fix is:
find / -name "terminalgpt"
 rm /Users/m/.npm/_npx/0e1ec426b0185841/node_modules/terminalgpt
rm -fr  /Users/m/.npm/_npx/0e1ec426b0185841/node_modules/terminalgpt

it is okay?

Comment: wait, maybe if it's a global instalation it doesn't need a package.json, did you try npm list -g? to see if the package really exists?

Comment: i will give you my conclusions,  i opened a terminal i went to desktop, and used npm install terminalgpt(all oke), it created a package.json, now with the terminal and located in desktop(because the package.json is loacted there), i tried npm uninstall -g terminalgpt, however nothing happened, all the dependency on package.json was there, so i used the same comand line npm uninstall terminalgpt, but without the "-g" of global, and it work fine, it got deleted. Now i think that you have a package.json, it got created, when you used the npm install ...  try to remember the path of the terminal

Comment: if you are using windows, you can open My Files, and up right, you will find a search bar, try and search package.json, and the one with the newest date should be the one

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to

> If any requested packages are not present in the local project dependencies, then they are installed to a folder in the npm cache, which is added to the PATH environment variable in the executed process.

— from [npx doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx#:%7E:text=if%20any%20requested%20packages%20are%20not%20present%20in%20the%20local%20project%20dependencies%2C%20then%20they%20are%20installed%20to%20a%20folder%20in%20the%20npm%20cache%2C%20which%20is%20added%20to%20the%20path%20environment%20variable%20in%20the%20executed%20process.)

that cache folder is like a temporary folder you don't have to specially care yourself about.

If you really want to clean your cache, see [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-cache) doc